# Regular expression to extract data

Tags: c#, regex

So I have a set of data that can look like this (sample line-by-line):

```
verkoop
verkoop [Hot News]
verkoop [Hot News] [Smurf]
verkoop test
verkoop test [Hot News]
verkoop test [Hot News] [Smurf]
```

what I want is for all the text (in this example it can be either `verkoop` or `verkoop test`) and all the tags (example: `[Hot News]` or `[Hot News]` `[Smurf]`) to be separated (in groups preferrably but eventually I just need these in an array in C#).

The text can remain 1 group but each tag must form it's own group.

I've tried to mess around with a regular expression but can't seem to be able to make it work with more than 1 tag (for example `[Hot News] [Smurf]`).
This is what I came up with:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)\s?(((?:[\[]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]+[\]]{1}\s?)*))$
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "in groups", and how would it be structured in the array? I'm not a RegEx expert, but this would be very trivial to parse using `IndexOf` and `Substring`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tags are always at the end of the string, you could simply split on the first occurrence of `[`, if it exists.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = "verkoop test [Hot News] [Smurf]";
        int i = s.IndexOf('[');
        if(i > -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, i));
            Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(i));
        }
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
verkoop test 
[Hot News] [Smurf]
```

Comment: Yeah I think this is probably the best way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @Fverswijver, yeah, it's perhaps a bit more lines of code, but far more readable than a single regex-split. And you're welcome, of course.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you consider simple string processing, in your case you can use "[" as a delimiter and split the string.